# Any way to edit data on MS-Access form using SQL View with two tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ms-access, stored-procedures, sql-view

From what I've read it should be possible to edit data described by a view if the data being modified represents only one table and a unique identifier field is included in the data.

According to Microsoft

> Any modifications must reference columns from only one base table

Has anyone had any luck creating an MS-Access form that is editable when the underlying recordset is based on a view or stored procedure merging data from two tables?

My form only used the secondary table to join a code table to get a text based description - but doing so makes the form uneditable.

Do I need to pull that out and create additional lookup code for the form? Or is there someone that can point me to an example that works for them?

This is what my view looks like now for the form I'm trying to use to edit `PreliminaryInvoices` table

```
SELECT        t1.*, t2.JobTypeGroup AS Grouping
FROM          dbo.PreliminaryInvoices AS t1 
INNER JOIN    dbo.tblJobTypes AS t2 
ON t1.JobTypeID = t2.JobTypeID
```

**EDIT - updated to show current working solution - no second table**

The only way I've been able to get it to work is to split out the second table and add a lookup to display the text from the JobTypeID

Current Editable View:

```
SELECT        t1.*
FROM          dbo.PreliminaryInvoices AS t1
```

Lookup procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spJobTypeGrouping]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @TypeID int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT  dbo.tblJobTypes.[Grouping] 
    FROM    dbo.tblJobTypes 
    WHERE   dbo.tblJobTypes.JobTypeiD = @TypeID
END
```

Comment: Try linking those SQL Server tables inside Access then bound needed form to their join and see if they are editable.

Comment: I don't use any linked tables. Lookup tables are created and pass thru queries, forms are dynamically attached at start and end of session. Client wanted more a bit more security

Comment: Pass thru queries are used for reports. Preference is to keep editable data queries on server, but I guess I might have to use linked tables if I come across any complicated queries used on forms

Comment: @Parfait You can use ADO to open a recordset with a pass-through query and bind that recordset to a form. That way you have an updateable form with a query that's executed on SQL server directly. It's a bit dubious if that's really called a pass-through query, but it often is.

Comment: @Parfait I assumed OP already did, else it would be a futile effort. An ADO recordset still needs to open a fully updateable view to get bound to an updateable form as far as I know, so my answer still stands, but I will add a bit about ADO recordsets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create `instead of` triggers on the view so you can update the the underlying table.  You don't have to update all of the fields in the trigger.  If you create the appropriate triggers, Access will treat it like a table.

As for fields that aren't covered by your trigger.  If a user tries to update the table, the UI will appear to modify fields, but if you reopen the view the original values will return.

Here's a trigger that will handle an insert, update, or delete.  Note that in the event of an update, insert and delete results sets are populated.  This isn't the most efficient way to handle things, but you're updating linked views in Access so...

```
CREATE TRIGGER vwInvoices_Modify ON vwInvoices
  INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS 

  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  -- delete non-updates
  DELETE FROM PreliminaryInvoices WHERE Id IN (
    SELECT Id FROM deleted EXCEPT SELECT Id FROM inserted
  );

  -- insert non-updates
  INSERT INTO PreliminaryInvoices (Id, colA, colB)
    SELECT Id, colA, colB FROM inserted WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM deleted)

  -- updates
  UPDATE PreliminaryInvoices SET
    colA = ins.colA
    colB = ins.colB
  FROM inserted ins
  WHERE ins.Id IN (SELECT Id FROM deleted)
    AND PreliminaryInvoices.Id = ins.Id

END
```

Comment: When you use `FROM inserted ins` where does that reference to `inserted ` come from? Is that a standard SQL Server table reference to the trigger table containing the table's new values? Same for `deleted`?

Comment: Yes, `deleted` and `inserted` are tables that are part of the trigger that are the deleted and inserted rows.  On update deleted and inserted are both populated.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update a view that's not fully updateable from within Microsoft Access, I recommend you use triggers in SQL server to execute the update.

You can define an `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` trigger to override the default update behaviour.

You can read about `INSTEAD OF` triggers on the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms179288%28v%3dsql.105%29). These allow you to specify exactly what happens when a field is updated, and even allow you to update calculated columns (for example, changing someone's birthdate when a calculated age column is changed).

To work with T-SQL queries and updateable views, you need to bind the form to an ADO recordset. You can use code similar to the following code:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    'Open a valid connection here. I recommend a reusable function or class for opening connections
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = conn.Open("SELECT * FROM dbo.MyView")
    Set Me.Recorset = rs
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not updating the extra table's field - just displaying it on the form and using it to lookup other data displayed on the form. The fact that it's in the view makes the view non-updateable.

Comment: Access doesn't do partly updateable. Something's either fully updateable, or not updateable. So, as said, use `INSTEAD OF` triggers, and just discard the irrelevant fields.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You will need to create a primary key after linking to the View.
Below is an example where `dbo_High_Priority_Missing_FollowUp` is a View on SQL Server that contains two joined tables. I placed the below code in a module and then execute it and it makes the linked table `dbo_High_Priority_Missing_FollowUp` editable.

```
S = "CREATE INDEX PrimaryKey ON dbo_High_Priority_Missing_FollowUp (ID) WITH PRIMARY"
db.Execute S
```